# Change dataset on d3 Tree drag n drop

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop, tree

Im trying to use d3 library to build a tree. So far Ive used this example (http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) and all works fine. 
Now once a node is dragged and assigned to another one id liek to get the new dataset/ the change and I was wondering could anyone advise how to do that ?Any help, leads would be appreciated.
Ive located the onDragEnd event I just dont know how to refer to the 'changed dataset'. Ideally Id love to call a WebAPI method and record the changes in the database..

Thank You, Neil

Comment: At the end of the dragend listener, `on('dragend'...)`, the `endDrag()` function is called. In this function there is a statement `update(root);` and if you log the results of this call by inserting `console.log(root);` in the next line, you can see that `root` now stores the changed dataset. You can then traverse this structure and store the desired info in your database.

Comment: Fantastic, Ill give a go and let You know. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes, so Ive tried what Youve suggested and the concept of it works but I cant do JSON.stringify(root), which Id post it then because I get an error ' Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON' ; If I dont stringify the function tries to pos the root object and I get 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' . I think I need to convert it into json but not sure how, any ideas ?

Comment: I just came across this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534883/d3-update-data-behind-the-visualization#22369507) while doing research on something else. It has a nice filtering function...check it out.

Comment: It is useful, but I think d3 tree structure under the hood has changed and that post doesn't really help. It gives a rough idea but it doesn't work, thanks for your comment tho